# SQL Server 2008 - SQL timeout exception on Insert Linq query

Tags: sql, timeout

Currently my windows service is processing approximately 1500 transacations a day. About once a week I get a random timeout exception on an Insert done using LINQ.

The exception is:

```
Exception (SqlException) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

The Linq query is:

```
dc.TransactionLoggings.InsertOnSubmit(new TransactionLogging()
                    {
                        DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        InputMessage = message,
                        DocId = documentID.ToString(),
                        TransactionStatus = transactionStatus
                    });
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Any ideas/suggestions on what to do to diagnose this??

Many thanks for your help,
Fiona

**UPDATE**

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionLogging](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[InputMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CCHMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DocId] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[TransactionStatus] [char](5) NOT NULL,
[DateAdded] [datetime] NULL,
[LastUpdate] [datetime] NULL,
[SentDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_TransactionLogging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY

Furthermore, the 2 most recent transaction timeouts occured for the first transaction of the day. This is no conincidence I'm sure!

Also just wondering if anybody has any thoughts on the following update to my code:

Any comments?!!!

```
 using (MiddlewareDBDataContext dc = new MiddlewareDBDataContext(ConfigurationWrapper.ActivityLoggingDatabase_ConnectionString))
            {

                dc.TransactionLoggings.InsertOnSubmit(new TransactionLogging()
                {
                    DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    InputMessage = message,
                    DocId = documentID.ToString(),
                    TransactionStatus = transactionStatus
                });
                try
                {
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    //Wait for 30 seconds then retry..
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give more time for command to execute to prevent the timeout. This could be done in the following way:

```
 using(var db = new DataContext()) 
   { 
      db.CommandTimeout = 60; // seconds
      // your queries ...   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madman. I had thought about that but was hoping to maybe figure out why this was happening rather than just increase the timeout. I'm right in saying I can do this through the config file also?

Comment: No, as far as I know this option can be set only in code. I advice you to check out the sql server log files. Maybe you'll find something. Maybe you have slow HDD or another request locks the table for a while during your requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQL Server may take a variable amount of time to do an operation. (An `INSERT` in particular may require more work than you might expect.) The concept of a timeout is there for a reason.

So I think the answer is that timeouts are a reality that your code needs to deal with. You could increase the timeout value, so you get the exception less frequently. But also, you should probably *catch* the exception and do something reasonable, such as try to insert again and/or relay the error condition to the user.

Comment: ok.. thanks for that suggestion. I think re-trying is a good one.. as currently its so infrequent.

Comment: Wearing your app developer hat, you should handle the exception. Wearing your DBA hat, if an `INSERT` timing out after 15 seconds, that is an interesting thing to chase down. Something is blocking the `INSERT`. 15 seconds seems like quite a long time for this to be a low-level issue such as disk I/O. I would look at long-running queries that are taking a lock on the table, what indexes need to be updated as a result of the `INSERT`, and so on. Depending on your situation and budget, a SQL consultant could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you get lucky that's going to take some work to track down. given you are doing 1500 a day and you are getting one of these a week, I'd go with what Greg H suggested and deal with it when it happens.

Default connection timeout is 60 seconds, default command timeout is 15 seconds. If it was a connection failure I'd expect to see some other operations failing for the same reason around the same time. You could increase the command timeout, but that would be symptom fixing in my opinion,  a pragmatic solution, but the nature of the issue suggests if you increase the load on the server, it's going to get worse, in which case thinngs could get silly.

I'd be looking at functions that do something heftty with the table, especially aggregate ones. Putting some sort of trace log around them might help you narrow it down. Definitley wonder if it's a worth while expenditure of effort though, given you have a 1 in 7500 failure rate in a five day operation. 1 in 10,000 on a 7 day...

Are there any triggers on this table by the way, if so they'll be worth looking at.

Comment: Its a command timeout exception from looking at the logs.. (timeout occurrs after 15seconds..) I was reluctant just to increase the timeout as I'd rather find the cause of it rather than treat the symptom as you've said. I probably should have mentioned that we're only live 3 weeks and so the db is relatively small.. but growing quickly. (up to 2G already) So I'm afraid that they will become more frequent. and no triggers on the table (or any table for that matter) I've perf monitor setup now. I did notice an increase in hard page faults from this at the time of the exceptions...

Comment: .. so I had another 4G of RAM added to the server. However we've had a further timeout since.. The insert is inserting large chunks of data - approximately 3500 bytes. no way around this.. we need to log the complete xml messages being received and sent..

Comment: Fumbling about in the dark here I'm afraid. Can you add the underlying table structure to the question. Also have you had a look for functions that use the table. Oh and completely off the wall you haven't got people linked to your live db for adhoc querying have you, say access or excel. Happened to me once that, a "you are doing WHAT"? moment.